# how can I change default Tinymce font size unit type from pt to px?

Tags: javascript, tinymce-6

The default font size unit type is `pt` but how can I change it to `px`?

Base on original source [font_size_input_default_unit](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/user-formatting-options/#font_size_input_default_unit) I set `font_size_input_default_unit: 'px',` but it doesn't work.

Please check this [example](https://codepen.io/ArshamCoder/pen/vYvKNbN).

I am using TinyMCE 6.7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `toolbar: "fontsize_formats"` to `toolbar: "font_size_formats"` which should display the options in `px`.